# Using Sql Function in virtual table error

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
        CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Get_LogoFaturaIskonto (
        @InvoiceRef     int = 0,
        @ParentlnRef    int = 0,
        @Rownumber      int = 0
    )
    RETURNS decimal(18,2)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @VALUE decimal(18,2)
        WITH NEWTABLE AS 
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LOGICALREF ASC) AS ROWNUMBER#
      ,DISCPER,LOGICALREF,INVOICEREF,PARENTLNREF FROM dbo.LG_002_01_STLINE 
    WHERE 
       INVOICEREF = @InvoiceRef AND PARENTLNREF = @ParentlnRef AND LINETYPE = 2)
        SELECT @VALUE = (SELECT * FROM NEWTABLE WHERE ROWNUMBER = @Rownumber)
        RETURN ISNULL(@VALUE,0)
    END
```

Erorr Message

Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Get_LogoFaturaIskonto, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Error message is self explanatory

Comment: Even the solution is suggested in the error message, did you try it?

Comment: By the way, `SELECT @VALUE = (SELECT * FROM...` is also going to give an error, since `NEWTABLE` contains multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

At least on missing semicolon:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Get_LogoFaturaIskonto (
    @InvoiceRef     int = 0,
    @ParentlnRef    int = 0,
    @Rownumber      int = 0
)
RETURNS decimal(18,2)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @VALUE decimal(18,2);

    WITH NEWTABLE AS 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LOGICALREF ASC) AS ROWNUMBER#
  ,DISCPER,LOGICALREF,INVOICEREF,PARENTLNREF FROM dbo.LG_002_01_STLINE 
WHERE 
   INVOICEREF = @InvoiceRef AND PARENTLNREF = @ParentlnRef AND LINETYPE = 2)
    SELECT @VALUE = (SELECT * FROM NEWTABLE WHERE ROWNUMBER = @Rownumber)
    RETURN ISNULL(@VALUE,0)
END
```